# How to go about writing a Structural Equation Model when there is not too much theory about the Research Question?

Tags: references, structural-equation-modeling

I have a Research Question where not much theoretical work has been done. Suppose I develop my own novel hypothesis to this question, and develop a structural model based on that. My question is how do I go about testing this model's validity?

I have a non-experimental dataset to work with. My knowledge in SEM is limited and so I am mainly looking for literature that answers my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might look at the book chapter called by Joreskog "Testing structural equation models", in the book "Testing structural equation models" by Bollen and Long.

In this chapter, Joreskog describes three approaches: Strictly Confirmatory (what everyone wants to do - test a specific model and either accept or reject it), Model Comparison (you have two or more theories to test with different models), and Model Generating (you have a tentative initial model, but want to adjust it). A lot of the chapter is available on Google Books [here](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=FvIxxeYDLx4C&oi=fnd&pg=PA294&dq=testing%20structural%20equation%20models&ots=_MWGBZWzBN&sig=PW19lI_pdjz6Kk4IkEcnbtflvpg#v=onepage&q=testing%20structural%20equation%20models&f=false).

Cross-validation is also important, to ensure that you are not simply capitalizing on chance.